# Android Studio doesn't see device for a particular project

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

I would just like to say first that my phone is detected properly in other projects, creating a new hello world project detects my phone, but it is not getting detected only on this **one particular project**

I am trying to compile the project here: https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleUsbTerminal

After the project loads in android studio and all the gradle syncing is complete, the drop down box next to the green play button (compile and download button) shows No Devices. Clicking on the Device File explorer tab also shows ADB connection could not be established. However,  my phone is properly connected and is detected in the terminal using `adb devices`. It also works normally if I load any other project, just not working on this one project. What could be the issue here? Is it even possible for

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following steps helped to resolve the issue:

1) Ensure the package "Google USB Driver" is installed in Android SDK Manager

2) Download "ADB Driver Installer 2.0" from here

3) Run the tool downloaded and connect your smartphone; in my case it showed that the driver had been installed incorrectly and suggested to fix it

After those steps my Android Studio instantly recognised the device! Both MTP and PTP started to work.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, solved and was thinking of asking then answering the question on StackOverflow until I saw this question.

Fix this by going to app build.Gradle file for the project then change target and compile SDK versions to 29, change dependencies also to match 29, then download SDK 29 and sources for android 29 by clicking the 'SDK Manager' tab, then click 'show package details' then download 'SDK 29' and 'download sources for android 29'.

I forked your project on GitHub, but after importing to android studio, android studio wasn't seeing my physical device. However, after applying the above changes, android studio was recognizing my physical device. The steps I explained above should solve your issue and if it does, let me know.